# reading and printing from txt file integers java

Tags: java, exception, text, readfile

I wrote the below code in order to read some integers from a text file and then print in a new txt every integer after I added the value ten to each of them. The "-1" int is as a pointer to show the end.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SmallChallengeCh {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = null;
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try{
            File f = new File("C:\\Users\\paioa\\primlnl.txt");
            in  = new Scanner(f);
            pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\paioa\\primOut.txt"),true);

            int num = in.nextInt();
            while(num != -1 ){
                num = num + 10;
                System.out.print(num + " ");
                pw.print(num + " ");
                num = in.nextInt();
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e1){
            System.out.println("The file does not exist");
        }finally {
            try{
                if(in != null) in.close(); else throw new Exception("NULL");
                if(pw != null) pw.close();else throw new Exception("NULL");
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I am getting the below error

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at gr.aueb.elearn.ch6.SmallChallengeCh.main(SmallChallengeCh.java:18)
Process finished with exit code 1**
```

But I cannot understand why. The inputmismatchexception is due to the fact that probably my file doesn't contain ints but that's not true here is the txt.

[Input of txt file, also saved with coding UTF-8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4tCb.jpg)

---

## Solved

ANSWER: The issue was with coding UTF-8. I should left the file ANSI. I don't know why the example I was reading/exercising on advocated this ..

Comment: at which number does it fail? or, how many numbers have been printed before the error?

Comment: this code is working fine for me without any issues output `19 18 20 `

Comment: I just ran this code against your input and it works fine.  Please [edit] your question with more information on how to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @AKSW it does not print any number in the console. Just creates a blank primOut.txt on the path i have  give on my code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int num;
while(in.hasNextInt()){
    num = in.nextInt();
    num = num + 10;
    System.out.print(num + " ");
    pw.print(num + " ");
}
```

If you want to read only integers before "-1" you have to do something like

```
int num;
while(in.hasNextInt()){
    num = in.nextInt();
    if(num == -1)
        break;
    num = num + 10;
    System.out.print(num + " ");
    pw.print(num + " ");
}
```